# The installation of the C compiler extension in PyCharm on Ubuntu system has failed

Tags: c, ubuntu, pycharm

When I tried to install the C program debugging extension as prompted in **PyCharm(2022.3)**, I encountered an error. My operating system version is **ubuntu23.04**. The specific error message is as follows:
"
非零退出代码 (1): /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn' /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unknown type [0x13] section` .relr.dyn' /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn' /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] section` .relr.dyn' /home/sci/anaconda3/envs/monai_study/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
"
It appears that you have located the libc.so.6 shared library in the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory.

Confirm/lib/x86_64-Linux-gnu/libc.so.6 present.

Comment: try sudo apt update followed by sudo apt install --reinstall libc6

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't work for me. Thank you